# Can I parametrize reportElement attributes somehow?

Tags: jasper-reports

Target is to manipulate elements position separately from view tags
Like this(non working):

```
<property name="col1_x" value="0"/>
<property name="col1_width" value="100"/>

<property name="col2_x" value="100"/>
<property name="col2_width" value="100"/>

<group name="Group1">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="$P{col1_x}" y="0" width="$P{col1_width}" height="20">
                    <property name="maybe.some.element.width?" value="$P{col1_w}"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Conlumn 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="$P{col2_x}" y="0" width="$P{col2_width}" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Conlumn 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group
```

Comment: The short answer is: **No**. It is not working with positions and sizes. In most cases the attributes are not dynamic. You can play with styles or with *net.sf.jasperreports.style.** properties. To build report dynamically it is better to use *JasperReports API* (vanilla or frameworks built on top of *JR*)

Comment: Use [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/features/). It lacks a friendly IDE, but provides the ability to have variable width columns. There are numerous examples that show how to [set a column's width](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-a-percentage-column/).